# Why can't I create an AVAudioFile on Mac Catalyst? (error -54)

Tags: avfoundation, avaudioengine, mac-catalyst, audiotoolbox, avaudioplayernode

My app lets users select an audio recording from their iTunes media library, then saves the media ID for later playback. From the media ID, I can use `MPMediaQuery` to get an `MPMediaItem`, then get the recording URL:

```
let recordingURL = mediaItem?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? URL
```

From the URL, I create an `AVAudioFile` that I can give to an `AVAudioPlayerNode` for playback:

```
do {
    let audioUnitFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: recordingURL)
} catch let error {
    NSLog("error loading AVAudioFile: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This all works fine on iOS. On Mac Catalyst, I can get a valid URL (I can see it's correct when inspecting it in the debugger), but the `AVAudioFile:forReading` function throws this error:

```
ExtAudioFile.cpp:193:Open: about to throw -54: open audio file
[avae]            AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioFile.mm:134:AVAudioFileImpl: (ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_extAudioFile)): error -54
error loading AVAudioFile: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error -54.)
```

I checked the Privacy settings in the Mac Settings app, and my app has permission to access the music library. What else can I check? What does error -54 mean? Is this supported with Mac Catalyst apps?

I'm using Xcode 12.5.1 on macOS 11.4.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I just found the problem. I needed to do:

```
recordingURL?.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
let audioUnitFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: recordingURL)
recordingURL?.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

I'm doing this with other files, but for some reason I didn't think to do it with media library files.